# How to wake up app using simple push notifications?

Tags: javascript, firefox-os, simple-push-api

I'm learning about the simple push API for Firefox OS apps. I understand that this will allow me to start an app that is closed when receiving a notification for it. Following [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/SimplePush) document, I was able to create a working app that can register an endpoint and receive notifications, but this only works if the app is open. I can even close the app, open it again without registering a new endpoint and notifications sent to the previous endpoint continue to work; but if the app is closed nothing happens.

I'm testing this on a phone running Firefox OS 1.4.

This is the code I have at the moment:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            navigator.mozSetMessageHandler('push', function(message) {
                document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = new Date();
            });
            navigator.mozSetMessageHandler('push-register', function(e) {
                register();
            });
            function register() {
                var endpoint;
                var request = navigator.push.register();
                request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                    endpoint = e.target.result;
                    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = endpoint;
                    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://192.168.1.6:8080/Servlet/endpoint?asd=' + encodeURIComponent(endpoint),true); //This sends the endpoint to my computer so I can ping it with curl.
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Push</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="register();">REGISTER</button>
        <br>
        <span id="log"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.webapp

```
{
    "name": "Push",
    "description": "push notifications.",
    "launch_path": "/index.html",
    "version": "1.0",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Lufte",
        "url": "https://github.com/lufte"
    },
    "permissions": {
        "push": {"description": "To receive notifications about the newest phone releases"}
    },
    "messages": [
        {"push": "/index.html"},
        {"push-register": "/index.html"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: what phone are you using?  Is the phone idle when the push happens? I wonder if you are running into this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1080752

Comment: I'm using an Alcatel OTF. I took a look at the bug (which basically renders push notifications useless despite the problem I am having, am I right?) but in my case the phone is not idle. I close the app, send a notification with curl from my computer immediately after, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a push message handler to handle the push message. Like this

```
if (window.navigator.mozSetMessageHandler) {
    window.navigator.mozSetMessageHandler('push', function(e) {
        console.log('My endpoint is ' + e.pushEndpoint);
        console.log('My new version is ' +  e.version);
        //Remember that you can handle here if you have more than
    });
} else {
  // No message handler
}
```

For more details please see [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Simple_Push_API#Add_the_push_message_handler)

Happy Coding

Comment: Sorry, I meant that this is what I was currently doing in my code (you can see the code in the question) but it still doesn't work. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @lufte did you solve your problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: @MeSa Ohh to be honest I don't even remember what this was related to. Sorry I can't help you.